# Flask: Set header on static files

Tags: python, flask

I've got the following flask route which serves static content:

```
@app.route('/static/<path:path>')
@resourceDecorator
def getStaticFile(path):
    return send_from_directory('static', path)
```

`@resourceDecorator` is declared as follows:

```
def resourceDecorator(f):
    def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
        resp = make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))

        resp.cache_control.no_cache = True                   # Turn off caching
        resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'    # Add header to allow CORS

        return resp
    return update_wrapper(new_func, f)
```

The decorator sets headers to deactivate caching and allow cross domain access. This works for my other, "regular" routes, but the files sent through the static route do not seem to get their headers set.

What's going wrong here?

Comment: Can you introspect the type of object returned by `getStaticFile`  view? Is it same is one of the types expected by `make_response` function? My doubt here is that `send_from_directory` returns some special object

Answer (score 1):

For static files, flask sets the default cache timeout to 12 hours/43200s hence your problem. You can change the default cache timeout in `send_from_directory` by passing the `cache_timeout` value directly since it uses the [`send_file`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.send_file) function to send a file to a client.

```
send_from_directory(cache_timeout=0)
```

Alternatively you can override the [`get_send_file_max_age`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.get_send_file_max_age).